# Guardar response de Api en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy trabajando con una app hecha con ReactJS, el caso es que llamo a una api que me trae unos datos que necesito para que el componente se monte. 
Lo que yo hice es hacer una funcion que guarde los datos de la api, lo setee en un state local y luego lo puedo usar desde ahi.
El problema es que, segun lei, no se puede utilizar `this.setState` dentro del `ComponentDidMount`, con lo cual haciendo esto en definitiva es lo que estaria haciendo. 
De que otra forma puedo almacenar los resultados y usarlos sin cambiar el state local?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData = async () =>
    getDataFromApi().then(response => {
      const { datos } = response.data;
      this.setState({ datos });
    });


  render() {
    const { datos } = this.state;
    return (
        {datos.length &&
          datos.map(({ nombre, apellido }) => (
            <Componente
```

Comment: Cuando hablas de `setState` usas `localStorage`?

Comment: ¿Dónde leyó que no se puede usar `setState` dentro de `componentDidMount`? Hasta donde sé es todo lo contrario.

Comment: Debe referirse a que ESLINT le salta la alerta, [https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-did-mount-set-state.md#prevent-usage-of-setstate-in-componentdidmount-reactno-did-mount-set-state] a mi tb me pasa en el proyecto en el que trabajo, no obstante no es una mala práctica según recoge la documentación oficial aquí: https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount.
No obstante este aproach te permite recargar los datos a posteriori, mientras que si lo tienes dentro del CDM, no podrías reutilizarlo.